# Proving bicontinuity of $\phi : \mathbb{R^+}\times S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C^+}$.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, differential-geometry

The function is given by $\phi(a,e^{i\theta}) = re^{i\theta}$, with $0\leq \theta<2\pi$.

I'm trying to prove that is an isomorphism of groups and also and homeomorphism, my teacher said we need to use the definition of continuity that use open balls, and while I don't have problem knowing what are the open balls in $\mathbb{C}$.

I don't know how the open balls in $\mathbb{R^+}\times S^1$ look.
Could you guys help me with that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is more natural to express $\phi$ as: $\phi(r,z)=rz$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $z\in S^1$). But then it is clear that $\phi$ is continuous. And $\phi^{-1}(z)=\left(\lvert z\rvert,\frac z{\lvert z\rvert}\right)$. So, it is also clear that $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Agree, actually there are many ways to prove continuity, but what i don't understand yet is to visualize a priori the open sets  of  $\mathbb{R^+} \times S^1$. I can send the opens of $\mathbb{C^x}$ with the inverse function but how you check it with the open.